Identify Tale: King kills Wife Out of Distrust Goes Blind then Regains Sight
Read a this tale long back need help identifying King.
It goes like one day King kills wife out of jealousy & distrust. Loses sight due to this event. Goes on penance realises his mistakes after guidance sage/god. Regains sight after asking for forgiveness. Renounces his kingdom & makes his mission to remove distrust among people.
Language: English 
Origin: India 
Period: Prehistoric India (Vedic Period) 
Last Read: Around 5-10 years back 
Source: Book about Kings & Legends (Don't remember exactly) 
